# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference

Tags: java

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`: Illegal group reference 
for following program

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String finalQueryString = "TAC: (dash_board or platform* or interfac* or portal* or app or (computer w5 (application or instruction*)) or program or software) and (educat* or ((work* or workforce or employment or job or career) w5 (skill or profile or expertise or abilit* or proficien* or competence or experience)) or train* or certifi*) and ((rank* or scor* or grad* or rate* or rating) w9 (educat* or skill or profile or expertise or abilit* or proficien* or competence or train* or certifi*)) and AC: (G06Q10/063112 or G06Q10/1053$)   ";
    System.out.println(String.format("(%s)", finalQueryString.trim()));

    String matchedValue = "L12";
    System.out.println(String.format("((?<!\\w)%s(?!\\w))", matchedValue));

    String parsedQuery = "SC:L12 not SC:L11";
    parsedQuery = parsedQuery.replaceAll(String.format("((?<!\\w)%s(?!\\w))", matchedValue), String.format("(%s)", finalQueryString.trim()));
    System.out.println(parsedQuery);
}
```

At parsedQuery Line I am getting Illegal group reference exception, I am not able to figure out why this is happening , can Someone figure this out?

Comment: You need to escape the `$` in `finalQueryString`, e.g. via `Matcher.quoteReplacement( finalQueryString )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a replacement string, `$` is a special character: it is used to grab matched groups from the pattern you are replacing

so you can use `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` for your replacement string like:

```
parsedQuery = parsedQuery.replaceAll(String.format("((?<!\\w)%s(?!\\w))", matchedValue), Matcher.quoteReplacement(String.format("(%s)", finalQueryString.trim())));
```

`quoteReplacement()` gives a `literal replacement string` instead of `regex`